# How to Enable canvas with Event during a animation clip

Tags: unity, animation

I want to enable a canvas while an animation clip is playing, I used animation Event and call the following script to enable the canvas, but the editor does not recognize any game object.

How a canvas can be enabled?

```
public void SetActiveTrue(GameObject game_object)
{
    game_object.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a conceptual problem, Animations are file assets in the project while GameObject is a reference to something in your active Scene(s). you cannot drag a Scene GameObject in an AnimationEvent but only prefabs. you can have a workaround:

- by passing a string and doing the lookup ? don't forget some defensive null checks.
- Having that animation directly in a parent of the Canvas so you can enable it directly in the timeline ?